# Using with open from other file

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python file were I want to add functions that I don't want to have in my main code like open csv files which is this case. The problem is when I want to invoke the function where I have the method "open with" the error:

> "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."

appears and for what I found this happens because indentation.

main.py:

```
from external_tools import read_csv
import unittest

class ClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_a(self):

        csv_file = "file.csv"

        csv_reader = read_csv(csv_file)

        for line in csv_reader:

            print(line[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

external_tools.py

```
import datetime
import csv

def epoch_converter():

    epoch_time = 40246871

    date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)

    print("Given epoch time: ", epoch_time)
    print("Converted Datetime: ", date_time)

def read_csv(csv_file):

    with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        print(csv_reader)

    return csv_reader
```

Is there any way to do it in this way or do I have to use open with in my main?

Comment: when you exit the `with` block, it automatically closes the file

Comment: @Matiiss i know, that's my problem, if there's any way to do it from external_tools.py or i need to add that open with in the main.

Comment: You probably want the `csv_file = open(...` syntax, not the `with open(...) as csv_file...` syntax. Using the `with` statement closes the file.

Comment: you can also just perform the action within the `with` block, like not separate that part in its own function

Comment: @SylvesterKruin yes, i was checking that option but i need to close the file later, open with do both

Comment: You could make `read_csv()` a generator instead of returning the `csv_reader` from it.

Comment: Whenever you want to close the file, you can just call `csv_file.close()`.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't making the generator in this case be as efficient as just reading in all of the file? how would making a generator here help? because since it is a file object it is bound to the underlying resource (per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)), meaning that the resource will get closed once you exit the `with` block, so a generator would require writing the entire thing in the memory?

Comment: You could make `read_csv` and [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) and use it with a `with` statement. You could even use [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) as a decorator to do it (with a minor modification to the function).

Comment: Is the file small enough that you could just read the whole thing into memory and return it as a list?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do what I suggested in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70525463/using-with-open-from-other-file#comment124667914_70525463), which was to turn `read_csv` into a context manager itself using `contextlib.contextmanager` as a function decorator.

`main.py`

```
from external_tools import read_csv
import unittest

class ClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_a(self):
        csv_file = "testfile.csv"

        with read_csv(csv_file) as csv_reader:
            for row in csv_reader:
                print(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

`external_tools.py`

```
import datetime
from contextlib import contextmanager
import csv


def epoch_converter():
    epoch_time = 40246871
    date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
    print("Given epoch time: ", epoch_time)
    print("Converted Datetime: ", date_time)


@contextmanager
def read_csv(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        yield csv_reader
    print('csv file closed')
```